# How can I send mySQL query data to the client faster in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET application, I am retrieving data from a mySQL database and sending it to the front end to be used in a graph.

In one case, the data contains about 2,700,000 rows, and this takes 15-20 seconds (I'm using the Stopwatch class to measure time between commands). I am trying the decrease the total time it takes for the user to get this data.

At least 10 seconds of this time is spent `.Read()`ing, even when nothing is done between reads, like so

```cs
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) {}
```

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```cs
List<object> results = new List<object>();

while (reader.Read())
    {
        results.Add(new { type = reader.GetValue(0), time = reader.GetValue(1),  value = reader.GetValue(2) });
    } // 10-15 seconds for 2.7 million rows

string jsonstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results); // 4 seconds

return jsonstr;
```

I've also tried turning the query result into a csv file, but both methods use a MySqlDataReader to .Read() line by line. **Is there a faster way to process the data points?**

Comment: Can you send it back in chunks?

Comment: The answer is that is kind of depends on the query you are running. There is almost certainly a way to get it to process faster, but to get a proper answer you will have to post your query. There might be a way to parallelize the workload, you may be able to use `yield return` to start sending back results earlier, etc... One big chunk of time is to serialize your results, so if you HAVE to work with JSON, this won't really be negotiable...

Comment: 2,700,000 rows is a ton of data regardless of how you optimize it. I would question why so much data is being retrieved in the first place.

Comment: I concur with all the existing suggestions in the comments, but also suggest using a faster MySQL connector library; MySqlConnector is almost twice as fast as Connector/NET at reading lots of rows: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector#performance